# Dynamic ROUND() on DECIMAL() type doesn't truncate trailing decimal places - MySQL

Tags: mysql, decimal, rounding, truncate

The MySQL ROUND() function is correctly rounding a value but not truncating trailing zeros when the second parameter to the function is itself some function and the value being rounded is a DECIMAL type.

Can someone explain what causes this behaviour?

Below query shows four situations:

1. A static round, works as expected
2. A dynamic round, where num of digits rounded is evaluated via IF(), does not truncate
3. A dynamic round, where num of digits rounded is evaluated via ROUND(), does not truncate
4. A dynamic round, where the value being rounded *can be* of a different type, works as expected

Sample query:

```
SELECT
    ROUND(val1, 3),
    ROUND(val1, IF(val1 < 5, 3, 3)),
    ROUND(val1, ROUND(val1)),
    ROUND(IFNULL(val1, '--'), IF(val1 < 5, 3, 3)),
    val1
FROM table_one;
```

Workbench output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okNPa.png). (Don't have the points to embed yet sorry)

Creating sample table with two entries:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_one` (
  `val1` decimal(20,10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO table_one VALUES (6.123423), (3.678903);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have to admit I am not sure of the reason that the `IF` does not work, but this does. the `c` result column is rounded as you wanted.

```
SELECT *, round(val1,3) as a,
    ROUND(val1, IF(val1 < 5, 3, 2)) as b,
    case when val1 < 5 then round(val1,3)
         when val1 > 6 then round(val1,2)
    end as c
FROM test.table_one;
```

RESULT

```
val1            a       b               c
6.1234230000    6.123   6.1200000000    6.12
3.6789030000    3.679   3.6790000000    3.679
```

Comment: What happens when  `val1 >= 5 AND val1 <= 6` ?

Comment: Thanks. This does work - but was hoping it could be avoided! The logic for 'val1' in my actual query is itself fairly complex and so was avoiding duplicating this if possible. Will have to do for now.